# node.js search and replace an exact string in json output using variables

Tags: javascript, json

I have found a LOT of posts that show how to do a search and replace for an exact string between quotes when using a wild card or direct search string. However when using variables in a `for` loop I am having trouble getting the correct syntax.

I have a number of keys in a json output from a db,

```
myJson = JSON.stringify(rowsMap);
```

gives

```
{
  "myStuff": [
    {
      "abc": "val_de_1",
      "abcxz": "val_xc_1",
      "mnabc": "val_abc_1"
    },
    {
      "abc": "val_de_2",
      "abcxz": "val_xc_2",
      "mnabc": "val_abc_2"
    },
    {
      "abc": "val_de_3",
      "abcxz": "val_xc_3",
      "mnabc": "val_abc_3"
    }
}
```

Now I would like to loop over the JSON and replace some of the key strings using a 2nd k:v pair

```
 for (var myVal in myPairs) {
        myJson = myJson.replace(RegExp(myVal, "g"), myPairs[myVal]);
        ....
        }
```

Now if the values are `abc` to `777` I get the following,

```
{
      "myStuff": [
        {
          "777": "val_de_1",
          "777xz": "val_xc_1",
          "mn777": "val_777_1"
        },
        {
          "777": "val_de_2",
          "777xz": "val_xc_2",
          "mn777": "val_777_2"
        },
        {
          "777": "val_de_3",
          "777xz": "val_xc_3",
          "777bc": "val_777_3"
        }
}
```

but I actually want

```
{
      "myStuff": [
        {
          "777": "val_de_1",
          "abcxz": "val_xc_1",
          "mnabc": "val_abc_1"
        },
        {
          "777": "val_de_2",
          "abcxz": "val_xc_2",
          "mnabc": "val_abc_2"
        },
        {
          "777": "val_de_3",
          "abcxz": "val_xc_3",
          "mnabc": "val_abc_3"
        }
    }
```

I have seen the use of brackets braces and variations of quotes before and after a literal string but not a variable.

What is the most efficient method for processing?
I have been able to do it in a cluncky manner

```
for (var myVal in myPairs) {

            myNewVal = "\""+myVal+"\"";
            myNewRep = "\""+myPairs[myVal]+"\"";
            myJson = myJson.replace(RegExp(myNewVal, "g"), myNewRep);
            ....
            }
```

Note I am looking for a solution where the regexp must look for the exact string between quotes, not include the quotes. The idea is to only do the `myNewRep` if the string is found, thereby making it faster I assume.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the json key string with `/[abc]/g`

This will replace the exact string.

some matches I tried.

abc - match
"abc" - match
abcd - Not match

http://www.regexpal.com/ - try this to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by quotes

'"abc"'.match(/"(.*?)"/)

Comment: this does not work with a variable as per the question. the regexp must look for the exact string between quotes, not include the quotes.